# Convert inner join ..OR into LINQ

Tags: linq

i been given a SQL inner join with OR condition, could someone help to convert into linq? Below is LINQ that i've converted except the "OR" condition

SQL

```
SELECT Msg.IntMsg
FROM CRM_MsgTbl Msg
    INNER JOIN CRM_TargetCustTbl TCust ON Msg.intCRM = TCust.intCRM
    INNER JOIN Cust_GroupDetailTbl CustGD ON TCust.intCustGroup = CustGD.intCustGroup
    INNER JOIN Cust_ProfileTbl
    ON  (Cust.bintAccountNo = CustGD.bintAccountNo OR TCust.intCustGroup=0) --How to convert this line to LINQ
```

LINQ

```
from Msg in db.CRM_MsgTbl
join TCust in CRM_TargetCustTbl on Msg.intCRM equals TCust.intCRM
join CustGD in Cust_GroupDetailTbl on TCust.intCustGroup equals CustGD.intCustGroup
join Cust in Cust_ProfileTbl on CustGD.bintAccountNo equals Cust.bintAccountNo
select new {
  intMsg = Msg.intMsg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from Msg in db.CRM_MsgTbl
join TCust in CRM_TargetCustTbl on Msg.intCRM equals TCust.intCRM
join CustGD in Cust_GroupDetailTbl on TCust.intCustGroup equals CustGD.intCustGroup
from Cust in Cust_ProfileTbl
where CustGD.bintAccountNo = Cust.bintAccountNo or TCust.intCustGroup = 0
select Msg.intMsg
```